# monit configuration under CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, monit

I am trying to do the following:

```
monit stop mysqld
monit: Cannot connect to the monit daemon. Did you start it with http support?
```

it only works when I stop the `monit` service.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your entire monit config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have embedded web server enabled. This `monit stop ...` command uses it internally.

```
# Monit has an embedded web server which can be used to view status of 
# services monitored and manage services from a web interface. See the
# Monit Wiki if you want to enable SSL for the web server. 

set httpd port 2812 and
    use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
    allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
    allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
```

Do change password if you omit this "use address localhost" line.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your monit config. The `monit stop` process references the name of the process defined in the configuration stanza. So if you have a config entry for MySQL, it should look like `check process mysql with pidfile...`

Your `monit stop` command should use the same name as the word following "process" in the configuration file.

Comment: set daemon 5
# Include all files from /etc/monit.d/
include /etc/monit.d/*


check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
group database
start program = "/etc/init.d/mysqld start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysqld stop"


if failed host 82.166.223.37 port 3306 protocol mysql then exec /usr/lib/heartbeat/hb_standby local